# Calculate y from x for a single label

Tags: gnuplot

I want to manually add a label in the graph at a certain x position by only entering x and calculate y from the datapoint.

e.g.:

[image: graph]

```
 1    set terminal png
 2    set output 'test2.png'
 3    
 4    x = 3
 5    y = 33
 6    set label "test" at x,y
 7    
 8    plot '-' using 1:2 with lines
 9      1 11
10      2 22
11      3 33
12      4 22
13      5 33
```

So, I don't want to hardcode "33" in line 5.

Is that possible?

---

(I have googled this question and inspected the possible duplicates offered by Stackoverflow after I entered the title. Nada.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 (data scan)**

For not too-large inputs, one could load the x/y data into two separate arrays and then locate the y-value corresponding to a given x-value:

```
$DATA <<EOD
1 11
2 22
3 33
4 22
5 33
EOD

stat $DATA nooutput
N = STATS_records

array data_x[N]
array data_y[N]
stat $DATA u (data_x[1+$0]=$1,data_y[1+$0]=$2,$1):2 nooutput

x0 = 3
y0 = NaN
do for [i=1:N] {
  if (data_x[i] == x0) {
    y0 = data_y[i]
  }
}

set label "test" at x0,y0

plot $DATA using 1:2 with lines t ''
```

The trick here is the second `stat` command which is used solely in order to populate the arrays `data_x`, and `data_y`. The expression `(data_x[1+$0]=$1,data_y[1+$0]=$2,$1):2` basically evaluates for each row in the data to `1:2`. However, due to the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), it has the side effect of setting the corresponding elements of `data_x`, and `data_y`.

**Method 2 (fitting)**

As an approximate alternative, one might fit a narrow Gaussian centered at `x0 = 3` to the input data set. If the characteristic width `sigma` of this Gaussian is smaller than the characteristic spacing between data points, then the amplitude should match the input y-value:

```
$DATA <<EOD
1 11
2 22
3 33
4 22
5 33
EOD

x0 = 3
sigma = 0.1

f(x) = a*exp(-(x - x0)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
fit f(x) $DATA using 1:2 via a
print a

y0 = a

set label "test" at x0,y0
plot $DATA using 1:2 with lines t ''
```

**Method 3 (external tool)**

As a more robust alternative, one could delegate this task to an external utility invoked in Gnuplot via the `system` call. The example is using `gawk` to scan the input data file. If it finds a matching value in the first column, it prints the corresponding y value and exits (so that only the first occurence is reported):

```
inputFileName = 'data.txt'

x0 = 3

getY(fName, x) = system(sprintf("gawk '$1==%d{print $2;exit}' '%s'", x, fName))

y0 = getY(inputFileName, 3)

set label "test" at x0,y0
plot inputFileName using 1:2 with lines t ''
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it does not work for me, because I have oversimplified my example. In reality, my x values are timedata, so for the first solution I get a "Stats command not available in timedata mode", and the second solution does not work either for obvious reasons. Anyway, my original question is properly answered. Thanks for taking that time :-).

Comment: @nst0022 in that case, I think I would use an external tool to find the y-value and instruct Gnuplot to invoke it via the `system` call. I have included an example.

Comment: Yes, no problem, and no need for an external tool. I already read through the data file in Python and prepare some Gnuplot code, which I include with `load`. With my  question I was just hoping there was some Gnuplot API call for this apparently trivial task :-).

Answer (score 1):

You say "manually", so maybe interactive placement is an option?  A mouse click on the desired location will load variables MOUSE_X and MOUSE_Y, which can then be used to generate a label.  There is a demo "mouselabels.dem" in the distribution that automates this and might be informative, but in essence you would do

```
plot FOO      # initial plot with no labels
pause mouse   # wait for mouse click
set label 1 "test" at MOUSE_X, MOUSE_Y
replot        # same plot with a label at the requested position
```

Comment: No, but there is quite some interesting stuff at your github mirror https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/tree/master/demo :-).