# Converting plot X, Y to location to draw arrow/line

Tags: gnuplot

I have a bunch of data that I'm plotting as point plots. The data is simply a column for X and a column for Y. The catch here though is this is plotted using axes x2y2.

The x1y1 is used for a histogram. The X axis is the same range for both plots.

I know how to derive the X coordinate, but am wondering if there is an easy way to determine the Y value to use to draw an arrow. I want to draw an arrow callout for an arbitrary point on the point plot.

y1 and y2 are independent.

Comment: you mean to get the `y` value for a particular `x` in the data file? If this is the case, this might be perhaps of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51593318/5351549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates for drawing the arrow can refer to different coordinate systems (`first`, `second`, `character`, `screen`, and `graph`, see `help coordinates`).

So, to draw an arrow e.g. from the top-middle of the plot (`graph 0.5, graph 1`) to `x2 = 1`, `y2 = 2` (`second 1, second 2`) you would write

```
set arrow from graph 0.5, graph 1 to second 1, second 2 head
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks this did it. I had read documentation on Coordinates, but clearly not well enough. I think one thing that threw me for a loop was I pre-binned my data. So calculating the X axis required me to factor this into account. So I assumed it wasn't a 1:1 mapping. I just tested using `first` and `second` as you prescribed and voila, success!